# Rendering dynamic components by selector name in shell application when using Micro Frontends

Tags: angular15

I'm using MicroFrontends in angular 15 ,
i want Rendering dynamic components from remote application in shell application
by selector name of components like

not by template variable for the component

please help me.
thanks.